Importing variable from package __init__ in python
I have a project structure as follows:
/src
    __init__.py
manage.py

In __init__.py, I have a variable app declared as app = Flask(__name__).
When trying to import the variable app into manage.py using from src import app, I get the error ImportError: cannot import name 'app' from 'src' (unknown location).
Reading other posts, it seems a common consensus is to use from . import app, which yields ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package.
How can I solve this?
EDIT:
I keep being asked for the __init__.py file. Here are the full contents of both files:
# src/__init__.py
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)

# manage.py
from src import app

The traceback for the error is as follows:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "---\Project\manage.py", line 1, in <module>
    from src import app
ImportError: cannot import name 'app' from 'src' (unknown location)

FINAL EDIT: It works now. No clue why; nothing has changed but it suddenly works. Cool.

Show us the contents of __init__.py.

@JohnGordon The only other important line is from flask import Flask. The same result is experienced when all other code is removed.

Have you installed your project as a package?

@EAW I have not. From what I am reading, that would seem to entail writing a setup.py or pyproject.toml for the package, neither of which I am aware how to do. If that does indeed work, further explanation would be appreciated!

You can only import from a package and not from a standalone script as python needs to know where to locate the imports you want. See https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/3.0.x/patterns/packages/ in the flask documentation for information to get you started.

As it currently stands, your code should work fine. If it's not, then there's something else you are not mentioning here. Please include the full traceback so we can help you.

@BcK I have included the traceback.

My goodness it's working now. I have absolutely no idea what or if anything is different but it works now. Thank you all for your help!

you can just import like that :
from src import app

but don't forget set before your from .src import * in your __init__.py
.
├── src
│   └── __init.py__
└── manage.py

src/__init__.py
test_var = 5

manage.py
from src import test_var
print(test_var)

test
python3 manage.py
5


If I am reading this right, you are saying adding from .src import * within the src/__init__ file should solve it? I've just tried this, along with from src import * and I do not seem to be getting a different result.

have you test "from src import app" ?
Can you share your __init__.py ?

I just added the full contents of both files.
